# link between private key and signed certificate in keystore

Tags: java, authentication, ssl, server-side, keytool

I am doing the `jetty SSL configuration`.

I have created CSR using keytool which  has added a private key to the keystore,

Received the certificate based on the CSR, converted the certificate to DER format and imported the certificate into the keystore as trustcacerts

The signed certificate has the root/intermediate certificates in the certificate path

I also installed the root and intermediate certificate in the IE under the trusted root certificate after converting it into DER format.

while using https , the browser shows certificate error and considers the certificate as self signed certificate.

**Question**

Does this mean the the installed signed certificate is not considered since the certificate does not have the Root/intermediate certificate in the certificate path?

Though the signed certificate received from the CA have the link to the root/intermediate certificate in the certificate path.

Please suggest if anything is wrong in the process . Adding the keytool commands followed for this.

Created keystore

> keytool -keystore serverdns.keystore -alias server -genkey -keyalg RSA
>   -keysize 2048

create CSR

> keytool -certreq -alias server -keystore serverdns.keystore -file
>   server.csr

installing signed certificate

> keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias cert -keystore serverdns.keystore
>   -file signedcert.der.cer

I have tried using the same alias 'server' while installing the signed certificate but it failed with the error

> keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Failed to establish chain from
>   reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import the signed certificate using the same alias as the private key and the CSR. Otherwise there is no connection between them, and the new certificate is just another certificate. You should not use `-trustcacerts` for this step, and if you are asked whether to trust the certificate you've got the alias wrong.

Comment: I have tried using the same alias but it fails with the error 'keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Failed to establish chain from reply' keystore details from keytool -list $ keytool -list -keystore serverdns.keystore
Enter keystore password:

Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

server, Apr 10, 2014, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (MD5): 40:00:B6:9F:60:EF:2C:1A:87:51:17:26:E2:BC:F4:0C

Comment: So you need to import the other CA certificates first, *with* the -trustcacerts option.

Comment: Used the same alias and imported the the intermediate certificate as trsuted CA certificate. It is working fine now. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

> keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Failed to establish chain from reply

Take a look at the option -trustcacerts, if your CA is in the truststore. 
Also you should have to add the CA's intermediate certificates to your keystore, before than signedcert.der.cer

Comment: I am using internet explorer to pass on the request and I have added the root and intermediate certificate does certificates root/intermediate have to be installed on the server keystore also? I am using the keystore as trustore

Comment: When you try to add certificate into server keystore, you have to add also CA certificate and intermediate certificate. Otherwise you cannot install certificate as -trustcacerts to server keystore

Comment: That argument is for the CA certs, not for the signed CSR.

Comment: we are writing the same thing..Does not make sense to add trustcacerts for generate a CSR